# Vue3 How to solve "Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'." error?

Tags: javascript, css, vuejs3, core-ui

Im working on some **Vue 3** app and using with bootstrap admin template called** Coreui.io (version: 4.2.0)**. So it deals with most of all the css styling things. When I change the page's size, shrink or grow it the error appears a few times. But it doesn't always show up.
(just like now and i cant share all the error description)

I research the error title but I encountered just jquery or vanilla js solutions about it.

The error:
**Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
TypeError: Failed to execute 'getComputedStyle' on 'Window': parameter 1 is not of type 'Element'.
at isOnMobile (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@coreui/vue/dist/index.es.js:7257:39)
at handleResize (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@coreui/vue/dist/index.es.js:7359:22)
at eval (webpack-internal:///./node_modules/@coreui/vue/dist/index.es.js:7337:47)**

I wanna know the reasons behind these errors.

(I will share the details when I encounter an error)

I wanted to create a web app with more than 10 pages. Encountered with this error sometimes.